# apache daemon procrun- java app as windows service- failing to start in 64-bit windows 7

Tags: java, apache, windows-services, daemon, procrun

my java application is successfully running in 32-bit Windows 7 as a Windows service. Recently I migrated to 64-bit.

I executed my procrun script and installed my service as I did previously for 32-bit os. It is displaying in services but failing in its launch. here is myService.bat:

```
cd\
C:
cd C:\myService_procrun
myService.exe //IS//myService --Install="C:\myService_procrun\myService.exe" 
--Jvm=auto --Startup=auto --StartMode jvm --StartClass com.imedx.myService.client.Processor 
--StartParams start -- StartMethod main --StopMode jvm --StopClass com.myService.client.Processor 
--StopParams stop --  StopMethod stop --Classpath="C:\myService_procrun\myService.jar" 
--DisplayName="myService" 
pause
```

the error what I'm getting when trying to start the service:

[image: Windows could not start the myService on LocalComputer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft srevice, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 0.]

It is showing the service specific windows error code 0.
When I checked the windows event log I found this:

> Service cannot be started. The handle is invalid

and the keyword is shown as:`0*80000000000000`

Are there any additional configurations required to run this service in a 64 bit environment?

Comment: I realized my mistake. I did not changed my 32-bit prunsrv.exe to 64-bit prunsrv.exe.. now it is working fine..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need 64 bit prunsrv.exe if your OS is 64 bit.